# QTableWidgetItem::setText segmentation fault

Tags: c++, qt, segmentation-fault, qtwidgets

I have this piece of code:

```
    temp = ui->barsTable->item(i, 1)->text().toUInt();
    if (temp > ui->nodesTable->rowCount())
    {
        QTableWidgetItem* bla = ui->barsTable->item(i, 1);
        /*ui->barsTable->item(i,  1)*/bla->setText(QString::number(ui->nodesTable->rowCount()));
    }
```

And it crashes on `setText`(QT debugger points to the `setText` function in `QTableWidgetItem` class). But `bla` is not nullptr and `temp` get text from this element correctly. Why does the error happen?

Comment: Did you try to rebuild your project?

Comment: Deleted folder with debug-build now and tried. Still error there.

Comment: What value does the variable have and how many rows does BarsTable have? the function item returns a pointer of the item if there is a QTableWidgetItem associated with a row and column and zero otherwise, thinking that bla is 0 so I recommend you encapsulate the last line with an if: `if(bla){bla->setText(QString::number(ui->nodesTable->rowCount()));}`

Comment: bla has not null adress, temp has correct value(which it must to have in this situation), barsTable has 2 rows. I can't encapsulate it because if my programm works right - there aren't null cells and this check - just ignoring the problem.

Comment: maybe ui->nodesTable is not initialized?

Comment: I think no, because ui was made in designer and initialize in MainWindow before all functions.

Comment: Check it with a debugger, and trying printing the value before setting the text

Comment: It is visible and working in program GUI. I think, table can't be uninitialized and visible in window.

Comment: And do you get the right value when printing with qDeubg?

Comment: Yes, all values are right. Even the value inside setText function is right.

Comment: Segmentation faults are tricky and can rise on a misleading part of the code. Is the object where this code is executed OK?